# Does anyone know about this postgres error

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgresql-12 installation I got the following errors in the postgresql.log.

WARNING:  The 1th level plan could not be stored in the entry whose pid is 2804422 because the entry could not find.

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."users" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR("pg_catalog".=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"

Does anyone now what kind of error this is.
I do not find anything about it on the web.

Comment: That looks like some 3rd party extension or plugin.  Are you using any of them?

Comment: Hello, I'm using pg_stat_statements, pg_show_plans